# Аутентификация в микросервисах

Tags: авторизация, аутентификация, микросервисы

Пишу учебный проект на микросервисах и не могу определиться со сценарием аутентификации.

Архитектура всего приложения выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько хорошим является сценарий при котором проверкой jwt токенов будет заниматься Gateway, и соответственно редиректить запрос на сервис аутентификации если токен не валиден?

С одной стороны из остальных микросервисов будет полностью убрана логика об аутентификации, а с другой кажется что это очень перенагрузит Gateway дополнительной логикой о проверке токенов.

Comment: что ты понимаешь под "проверкой jwt токенов"?

Comment: Да наверняка там как-то кэшируется инфа о токенах, так что не думаю, что там прям уж сильная нагрузка на gateway от этого.

Comment: @Grundy Предполагается что у сервиса аутентификации будет приватный ключ, которым он будет подписывать откены, а у Gateway будет публичный, с помощью которого тот будет их проверять на валидность. Сам процесс проверки заключается в том, что извлекается header и payload из токена, публичным ключем генерируется подпись и сравнивается с подписью в токене, затем проверяется время его жизни (просрочен ли).